integration cannot persist catalog
I'm trying to setup a sample data-lakehouse using flink and iceberg. My purpose is to integrate it with minIo and nessie.
After an hard battle with Flink image, this is my setup
Flink dockerfile:
FROM flink

RUN wget https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/iceberg/iceberg-flink-runtime-1.19/1.6.1/iceberg-flink-runtime-1.19-1.6.1.jar && \
    mv iceberg-flink-runtime-1.19-1.6.1.jar /opt/flink/lib

RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y openjdk-11-jdk-headless && \
    apt-get install -y build-essential liblzma-dev libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev libffi-dev xz-utils && \
    wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.11.10/Python-3.11.10.tgz && \
    tar -xvf Python-3.11.10.tgz && \
    cd Python-3.11.10 && \
    ./configure --without-tests --enable-shared && \
    make -j6 && \
    make install && \
    ldconfig /usr/local/lib && \
    cd .. && rm -f Python-3.11.10.tgz && rm -rf Python-3.11.10 && \
    ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-arm64"
RUN export JAVA_HOME

ENV HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/opt/hadoop

RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip && \
    pip3 install apache-flink

RUN \
    wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-common/3.4.0/hadoop-common-3.4.0.jar && \
    wget https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/flink/flink-sql-connector-hive-3.1.3_2.12/1.20.0/flink-sql-connector-hive-3.1.3_2.12-1.20.0.jar && \
    wget https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/flink/flink-shaded-hadoop-2-uber/2.8.3-9.0/flink-shaded-hadoop-2-uber-2.8.3-9.0.jar && \
    wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/software/amazon/awssdk/bundle/2.9.9/bundle-2.9.9.jar && \
    mv hadoop-common-3.4.0.jar /opt/flink/lib/ && \
    mv flink-sql-connector-hive-3.1.3_2.12-1.20.0.jar /opt/flink/lib/ && \
    mv flink-shaded-hadoop-2-uber-2.8.3-9.0.jar /opt/flink/lib/ && \
    mv bundle-2.9.9.jar /opt/flink/lib/

RUN wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/iceberg/iceberg-aws-bundle/1.6.1/iceberg-aws-bundle-1.6.1.jar && \
    mv iceberg-aws-bundle-1.6.1.jar /opt/flink/lib/

docker-compose.yml
x-common-variables: &aws_env
  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: minioadmin
  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: minioadmin
  AWS_REGION: us-west-1
  AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: us-west-1

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.4.0
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      <<: *aws_env   # Include the common AWS environment variables
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  minio:
    image: minio/minio
    environment:
      MINIO_ROOT_USER: minioadmin
      MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: minioadmin
      <<: *aws_env   # Include the common AWS environment variables
    command: server --address ":9000" --console-address ":9001" /data
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
      - "9001:9001"
    volumes:
      - ./minio/data:/data

  nessie:
    image: projectnessie/nessie
    ports:
      - "19120:19120"
    environment:
      QUARKUS_HTTP_PORT: 19120
      QUARKUS_PROFILE: inmemory
      <<: *aws_env   # Include the common AWS environment variables

  flink-jobmanager:
    build:
      context: ./flink
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      FLINK_PROPERTIES: "jobmanager.rpc.address: flink-jobmanager"
      <<: *aws_env   # Include the common AWS environment variables
    command: jobmanager
    volumes:
      - ./flink:/opt/flink/scripts
    depends_on:
      - kafka
      - minio
      - nessie

  flink-taskmanager:
    build:
      context: ./flink
    environment:
      FLINK_PROPERTIES: "jobmanager.rpc.address: flink-jobmanager"
      <<: *aws_env   # Include the common AWS environment variables
    volumes:
      - ./flink:/opt/flink/scripts
    depends_on:
      - flink-jobmanager
    command: taskmanager

The script I'm trying to run inside the flink container is:

from pyflink.datastream import StreamExecutionEnvironment
from pyflink.table import StreamTableEnvironment
import os

env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment()

table_env = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env)


table_env.execute_sql("""
    CREATE CATALOG iceberg_catalog WITH (
      'type'='iceberg',
      'ref'='main',
      'uri'='http://nessie:19120/api/v1',
      'catalog-impl'='org.apache.iceberg.nessie.NessieCatalog',
      'warehouse'='s3://lakehouse',
      'io-impl'='org.apache.iceberg.aws.s3.S3FileIO',
      's3.endpoint'='http://minio:9000',
      's3.access-key'='minioadmin',
      's3.secret-key'='minioadmin',
      's3.region'='us-west-1',
      's3.path-style-access'='true'
    )
""")
table_env.execute_sql("use catalog iceberg_catalog")
table_env.execute_sql("create database iceberg_catalog.raw_data")

table_env.execute_sql("""
    CREATE TABLE iceberg_catalog.raw_data.sensor_data (
        id INT,
        time TIMESTAMP(3)
    ) PARTITIONED BY (sensor_id)
""")

# Lettura da Kafka e scrittura su Iceberg
table_env.execute_sql("""

The first problem I get is the error in the table creation:
Caused by: software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.RetryableException: Data read has a different checksum than expected. Was 0xd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e, but expected 0x0c056867bb4fcfb666cc4b65b34c05ac. This commonly means that the data was corrupted between the client and service. Note: Despite this error, the upload still completed and was persisted in S3.

After that I see some files using MinIO UI, in fact a metadata file has been created after executing this.
But the other problem is that, if I try to access to this catalog using, for example, another script, the catalog is missing i.e.
running
table_env.execute_sql("show catalogs").print()

I got only:
+-----------------+
|    catalog name |
+-----------------+
| default_catalog |
+-----------------+

like the iceberg_catalog is not persisted (but I still see some metadata in the correct directory on MinIO.
Does anyone have some ideas? Thanks
